# Windows Server 2008r2 Backup cannot do full backup on selected folders

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-backup

I have two shared folders on our Windows Storage Server 2008r2 I want to backup every week. But when I attempt to restore, I realize that Windows Backup did not perform a full backup of my two selected folders. Only the first folder is available for restoring. Moreover, the subfolders in the first folder is incomplete as well.

How do I force Windows Backup to perform a full backup of my selected folders? And if only the first backup is a full backup, how can I trigger it to perform a full backup again when the first backup is deleted? I suspect that it is only performing an incremental backup and my daily previous version snapshot might affect Windows Backup?

btw, will doing a VSS reset wipe off all my previous versions?

Comment: I found that Windows Server Backup has many restrictions.

1. It can't backup whole volume if exceed 2TB

2. It can't backup files selection if exceed unknown factor. The backup will have many missing subfolders and files. I have to split into multiple backups. This also mean that I can't depend on scheduled backup because it can only do 1 backup job.

3. It can't backup files that has all users permission removed except for the authorized user. So we have to go thru all the subfolders one by one to check on the permission which is extremely time consuming.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You can always **update your own question** with additional information, new insights and/or further refinement, please don't use comments for that. Thanks!